# How to create tabs inside a tab in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to create three tabs inside a tab in ionic 3 but, i can't get it working.

[Here is an example of what i trying to do](https://codepen.io/TWangCoin/pen/KpLwJe), but it seems to have been achieved with an earlier version of ionic. i am using ionic 3.10.3

ionic -v from the CLI prints 3.10.3

Here are some information from my project.

I have a main page with three tabs (Home, Message, Setting) and i want to create three other tabs(All, Read, Unread) inside the Message tab content.

Here are the content of my projet

**main**

```
/src/pages/main/main.ts
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { SettingPage } from '../setting/setting';
import { MessagePage } from '../message/message';


@Component({
 selector: 'page-main',
 templateUrl: 'main.html'
 
})

export class MainPage {
 tabHomeRoot : HomePage;
 tabSettingRoot: SettingPage;
 tabMessageRoot: MessagePage;
 
 constructor(){
    
 }
}
```

```
/src/pages/main/main.html
```

```html
 <ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabHomeRoot" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabMessageRoot" tabTitle="Message" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabSettingRoot" tabTitle="Setting" tabIcon="gear"></ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs>
```

The content of the other tabs are basic, so i am only going to put the content of The message tab

**message**

```
/src/pages/message/message.ts
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';

import { AllMessagePage } from '../all-message/all-message';
import { ReadMessagePage } from '../read-message/read-message';
import { UnreadMessagePage } from '../unread-messag/unread-message';


@Component({
 selector: 'page-message',
 templateUrl: 'message.html'
 
})

export class MessagePage {
 tabAllMessageRoot : AllMessagePage;
 tabUnreadMessageRoot: UnreadMessagePage;
 tabReadMessageRoot: ReadMessagePage;
 
 constructor(){
    
 }
}
```

```
/src/pages/message/message.html
```

```html
<ion-content>
  
 <ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabAllMessageRoot" tabTitle="All"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabUnreadMessageRoot" tabTitle="Unread" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabReadMessageRoot" tabTitle="Read" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs>

</ion-content>
```

Any help will be appreciate, Thanks

Comment: so what issue are you facing here?

Comment: The content of the message tab does not display the nested tabs. It should display three tabs : All, Unread and Read

Answer (score 6):

If I have not mistaken your question, then I suggest that you check out ion-segment component. Click [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/) to see the documentation.

So, in the message.html page, you should add this:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="selectedSegment" (ionChange)="onSegmentChanged($event)">
  <ion-segment-button value="all">
    All
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="read">
    Read
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="unread">
    Unread
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

Then, add some function to the message.ts file to reflect what you did here.

```
onSegmentChanged(segmentButton: any) {
  this.selectedSegment = all; //all, read, unread
  this.showAll = true;
  this.showRead = false;
  this.showUnread = false;
}
```

Lastly, just use *ngIf to enable or disable content based on what you have chosen for the selectedSegment.

```
<ion-content>
   <ion-item *ngIf="showAll"></ion-item >
   <ion-item *ngIf="showRead"></ion-item >
   <ion-item *ngIf="showUnread"></ion-item >
</ion-content>
```

Comment: @eyan durian, Segments indeed are like Tabs, and could be used for some case. In some scenario where you need to embed an entire page, for example the result of an ajax request, i think tabs are better.  I am going to use Segment. But for those who are planning to use segment as solution, they could have a look at this github page. They use ngSwitch. it is more simple. [link](http://https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-preview-app/blob/master/src/pages/segments/basic/template.html) . Thank ieyan durian, Your answer save me time

Comment: I have done same but child page content not displaying.
Please refer my issue [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-segment-inside-ionic-tab-not-displaying-child-page-properly/176151).

Answer (score 0):

This question shows up as #3 on Google search when searching for "ionic 3 tabs example". Since there is no answer, I can't imagine how much time it has wasted people coming here hoping for an example.

I've wasted hours because I took some what I assume was ok looking code from you original question. It probably doesn't matter to you now but for whomever Google sends here, one of the major problem was:

You need add “=” sign instead of “:” ,

```
export class MessagePage {
tabAllMessageRoot : AllMessagePage;
tabUnreadMessageRoot: UnreadMessagePage;
tabReadMessageRoot: ReadMessagePage;
```

should be

```
export class MessagePage {
tabAllMessageRoot = AllMessagePage;
tabUnreadMessageRoot = UnreadMessagePage;
tabReadMessageRoot = ReadMessagePage;
```

I've wasted hours of my time, hopefully this helps someone else.

Lesson learned about taking code from unanswered questions!